Reading a JSON file
I need to write a file that can be appended (and not overwritten!) and then to read this file. This is the code I wrote:
import io, json

def WriteJSON():
    Taskslist = [["1Name", "1c:/path/file.ext", "1Some other text", 10, ["a", "b", "c"], ""],
                 ["2Name", "2c:/path/file.ext", "2Test text", 20, ["a", "b", "c"], ""]]

with io.open('test.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    str_ = json.dump(Taskslist, outfile)

def ReadJSON():
    with io.open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as readfile:
        rf = json.load(readfile)

    return rf

WriteJSON()
print(ReadJSON())

When I execute this program I get an error:

'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 149 (char 148)'

But if I change the file to be written (with the 'w' option and not 'a' option) the file write and read is OK.
I saw the solution is to read line by line the JSON file but as I understands the json.dump writes the file by one stuck, so it's one line....
My goal is to write a file than can be updated (append or delete data) and can be read any time the user asks for. I don't really need JSON file, so any other solutions can be suggested.

This is fundamentally not a Python question. You cannot append to an existing JSON file to write additional JSON data because the JSON data format does not work that way.

you can't append to existing JSON because it creates incorrect file. This way you create Multi-JSON (if new data is formatted as one line) and it may need to read it line by line (as normal text file) and later convert every line to JSON data. And later you have to join data from all JSON. Maybe better write it as CSV (if you can)

JSON is a nested structure and can't be appended to, but JSONL (JSON Lines) can.  In the latter case write each JSON as a single newline-terminated line:
import json

def WriteJSON():
    Taskslist = [["1Name", "1c:/path/file.ext", "1Some other text", 10, ["a", "b", "c"], ""],
                 ["2Name", "2c:/path/file.ext", "2Test text", 20, ["a", "b", "c"], ""]]
    with open('test.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        print(json.dumps(Taskslist), file=outfile)  # print adds the newline

def ReadJSON():
    # Read each line, decode JSON and collect in a list.
    with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as readfile:
        return [json.loads(line) for line in readfile]
    return rf

# Append a few times...
WriteJSON()
WriteJSON()
WriteJSON()

print(ReadJSON())

Output:
[[['1Name', '1c:/path/file.ext', '1Some other text', 10, ['a', 'b', 'c'], ''], ['2Name', '2c:/path/file.ext', '2Test text', 20, ['a', 'b', 'c'], '']], [['1Name', '1c:/path/file.ext', '1Some other text', 10, ['a', 'b', 'c'], ''], ['2Name', '2c:/path/file.ext', '2Test text', 20, ['a', 'b', 'c'], '']], [['1Name', '1c:/path/file.ext', '1Some other text', 10, ['a', 'b', 'c'], ''], ['2Name', '2c:/path/file.ext', '2Test text', 20, ['a', 'b', 'c'], '']]]


The json format requires exactly one outermost object in the file -- typically a list or a dictionary. So your requirement of being able to append to the file later on won't work (unless you rewrite the file a little bit).
One common way around this is to not have a strict json file, but instead have a file where each line in the file is a separate little json record:
[1,2,3,4,5]
["hello", "goodbye", "adios"]
{"a": 1, "b": 2}

This format is often called "json lines".
